# Меня сушит жажда. (I'm thirsty, I have a thirst for smth to drink.) Это тавтология, усиление или уточняющее определение?

Tags: перевод, этимология

Мы говорим: меня сушит.

```
Голос Паклина беспрестанно обрывался, как у человека, которого сушит и мучит жажда.
                                                            [Тургенев. Новь (1877)]
```

В литературном языке глагол ["сушит" употребляется в значении](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F+%D1%81%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%22&tbm=bks):
а) субъект имеет желание, и это желание его сушит; или
б) нечто действует на субъект как причина, и субъект сушится от причины.

Желание у субъекта есть активное действие, направленное на объект, мы говорим: субъекту хочется иметь объект. Объектом может быть не только вещь, но и процесс. Например: *пить, уехать, курить...* При этом в литературной речи соотношение желаний
[пить/делать что-то др.] = 10/90.

Для тургеневского "Человека сушит жажда" мы рассмотрим три примера:

```
Человека сушит жажда денег.         (1)
Человека сушит жажда пить.          (2)
Человека сушит жажда.               (3)
```

И (1), и (2) допустимы, но в (3) не указан объект. Следовательно, Тургенев предлагает читателю взять объект из контекста. Из контекста понятно, что слово "жажда" нужно понимать как желание пить. Следовательно, **Тургенев применяет не тавтологию, усиление или уточнение, а наоборот, экономное сокращение слов, не называя объект, который понятен из контекста.** (всё правильно?)

---

Ниже я представлю заготовку(unfinished scheme), и было бы интересно разобрать это всё в английском. Во что превращается слово "жажда"?

```
thirst (n.) — Old English thyrre, root *ters- "dry" (see terrain)
                                              сушить       суша


thirst (n.)
  |         in desire (?)
  |       /
 ters --- 
          \  in need of a drink (?)
```

Кстати,

```
  сухой, сушеный хлеб = черствый хлеб 
            ┌──same sounds──┘      
         thirsty
```

Comment: А вы с какой целью интересуетесь? (с)

Comment: Лично я воспринимаю как усиление: "мучит жажда" - "сушит и мучит жажда".

Comment: @user4419802 , я о другом, если `Человека сушит` = `У человека жажда`, то `человека сушит жажда` выглядит как тавтология.

Comment: @Avtokod "Человека сушит" выглядит как просторечие.

Comment: @Avtokod: it's a tautology indeed, or rather a pleonasm, a rhetorical device.

Comment: Думаю, что этот вопрос больше подходит для http://rus.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Устоявшееся уточняющее определение. Слово "сушит" без слова "жажда" по отношению к человеку часто означает похмелье (hangover). В литературном языке выражение "человека сушит" обычно не употребляется без слова "жажда", чтобы не быть вульгарным, просторечным.

Все это справедливо только к одушевленным (людям, животным) объектам. Для всего остального слово "сушить" употребляется в буквальном значении.

Comment: Гоголь вульгарен, когда про себя говорит "Она меня сушит."?

Comment: Нет, потому что "она", очевидно, относится к жажде.